CONST warning of blue squiggles not showing for Flutter development
I use VS Code for my Flutter-Dart development and suddenly I see that my editor is not giving me the blue squiggly lines for 'const'. These lines were a great help for me to know where I can put const without troubles. I tried to search for the solution through the internet, like YouTube videos and stuff but there seems to be no  solution. I tried asking ChatGPT but it's telling me to update my editor or update extensions. I have everything updated I have double checked. Did I turn something off? The solutions that I found are mainly telling me how to automatically add const without having to manually do it each time, which can be good solution to my problem but I liked adding const manually.

Have you found a solution?
I had the same problem and was able to fix it by adding the following line to the analysis_options.yaml file under rules:
prefer_const_constructors: true
The line was mentioned in this stackoverflow.
